# 共有フォルダへの接続エラーについて

Tags: c#

WNetAddConnection2により、共有フォルダへログインする際の質問です。
相手先の端末が起動していない場合、応答なしで固まってしまいます。
回避方法はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

例えば、`WNetAddConnection2`の前に`ping`を打ってみるとか？
まあ`ping`を打ちあっても問題ない環境構築・設定を済ませている必要はあるでしょうが。

他には、`WNetAddConnection2`を行うだけの単機能の`.exe`を作成して子プロセスとして起動し、
それがタイムアウトと決めた時間内に終了してこない場合に、強制終了させるとか。
あるいは同一プロセス内でも`Task.Run`とか`async/await`にすれば、同等のことが出来るのかもしれませんが。

`ping`系はこんな記事があります。
[C#でPingしてみよう](https://qiita.com/Argent0159/items/a5cec41fc7d2c74c2c0e)
[ネットワーク経由で「いる／いない」を確認する5つの方法](https://www.itmedia.co.jp/bizid/articles/0701/24/news078.html)
[Windowsの「ping」コマンドでネットワークトラブルの原因を調査する (1/2)](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0012/01/news002.html)
(2/2)は会員登録(無料)が必要

英語版S.O.で`CancelSynchronousIo`でキャンセル出来るかも？とありましたが結局無理とのこと。
[How to achieve the equivalent of WNetAddConnection2 with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9323023/9014308)
[Does CancelSynchronousIo work with WNetAddConnection2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9475581/9014308)

Task.Run, async/awaitの記事例
[初心者のためのTask.Run(), async/awaitの使い方](https://qiita.com/Alupaca1363Inew/items/0126270bca99883605de)

Comment: pingは打てる環境であるため、ping送信処理をWNetAddConnection2の前に追加しました。結果、応答なしになることはなくなりました。ありがとうございました。